# How to create a common message file in lumen framwork

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have an API setup with the PHP  Lumen framework, I want a common service file or maybe a helper which contains all the messages I will pass to the client. It is not something I am looking for localization, I need the best way to have a common message file ( this could be anything I will pass to the client ). When it comes to changing the message we have to find it in the models or in services and then we fix it which sucks, I think this way is much better in that case.

Comment: what is the issue with going with the localization way? Just add all the messages to a single language file ( english) ?

Comment: I think that makes sense but it's not going to be a multilanguage app, so I think going with localization will not be a good choice. Or may be that is the last option

Comment: why do you think that's not a good choice? It is. You can always localize in future if needed without the headache,.

Answer (score 1):

### Using keys in your localization files

With this way you will reach two goals.

1. **messages are in one place!**
2. **you can localize them!**

As an example:

```
{
  "register.duplicateUser": "user already exists"
}
```

Use it like

```
echo __("register.duplicateUser");
```